# How do I specify the Django view action decorator for an endpoint with multiple parameters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For the view and endpoint below with multiple parameters, how should `url_path` be specified for the action decorator?

urls.py:

```
router.register('utils', views.TableColumnViewSet, basename='TableColumn')
```

views.py:

```
@action(detail=False, url_path=r'???')
def table_meta(self, request, catalog=None, schema=None, table=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to find an example with multiple params.  The trick is realizing that each parameter in the query string is a "named backreference".  Realizing this, the syntax makes total sense: name each param as a backreference, with parentheses.

url:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/utils/table_meta/my_db/my_schema/my_table/
```

views.py:

Note the [named group syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups): each param is surrounded with parentheses and the `?P<name>` syntax names the group:

```
@action(detail=False, url_path=r'table_meta/(?P<catalog>[^/.]+)/(?P<schema>[^/.]+)/(?P<table>[^/.]+)')
def table_meta(self, request, catalog=None, schema=None, table=None)
```